# Timing STL Containers - Wide Variation?

Tags: c++, stl, performancecounter

I'm using the following method to time some operations on STL containers vector, deque, list, multiset, and multimap.

```
PrecisionTimer::PrecisionTimer()
{
   LARGE_INTEGER cps;
   LARGE_INTEGER init_cnt;

   QueryPerformanceCounter( &init_cnt );
   QueryPerformanceFrequency( &cps );

   start_count = init_cnt.QuadPart;
   microseconds_per_count = 1000000.0 / cps.QuadPart;
}

void PrecisionTimer::ReStart()
{
   LARGE_INTEGER init_cnt;
   QueryPerformanceCounter( &init_cnt );
   start_count = init_cnt.QuadPart;
}


// in microseconds
unsigned int PrecisionTimer::ElaspedTime() const
{
   LARGE_INTEGER cnt;
   QueryPerformanceCounter(&cnt);
   return (unsigned int)( ( cnt.QuadPart - start_count ) 
                         * microseconds_per_count + 0.5 );
}
```

The process is simply this:
I have a listbox full of strings, move them to a vector, and then add elements from the vector to the STL container. Then I remove all of the elements from the container and receive the time it took in microseconds.

My question is about variation: Sometimes my trial is 60,000+ microseconds different than the first one. Why? Is it to do with the timer implementation? I've been pointed in the direction of effects of timeslicing and high-speech cache. Can anyone elaborate on that? Does CPU usage affect it?

I'm not asking for a better implementation of a timer. I'm asking why it varies.

Comment: The same reason it takes an hour for the clock to go from 4:55pm to 5:00pm on a Friday - aliens!

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?  Are you sure that the code you're timing isn't being optimized out if it doesn't have side effects?  Without seeing the tests you're running it's pretty hard to guess.

Comment: Your timing tests are meaningless if you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the proper way to show it, but here is a link to a video showing the testing.

http://tinypic.com/r/2r462pw/8

The project source code and GUI is all done in Visual Studio 2012. Not sure if that answers anything about your compiling questions.

Comment: That video shows nothing useful about the code of the tests you are running or if you are compiling with optimizations or not.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, there are a small number of cpu cores in the system, yet there are a large number of processes running simultaneously. In order to achieve this, the OS will allocate time to a process before doing the same for the next one and so on. Depending on what programs are doing, they may need none-of, some-of or all-of their time-slice. As this varies, as can the number of processes running, you can have a variable period of time between each time your code is called - which when combined with constant execution time of your own code, leads to a different number of seconds elapsed on the wall-clock from when you started your program up until the time that it completes.

Since the `QueryHighPerformance` function returns time elapsed on the wall-clock, it doesn't take into account these differences in scheduling and thus it reports a varying quantity as the time required to execute the same code with the same data. The ideal timer would return the time consumed by your process only - much like the "CPU Time" column available in the Win7 Task Manager (View->Select Columns-> CPU Time)